# Show message box when page opens in Windows RT

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

How can I show message box when a page has opened? This is the code for my WP project, but I want to know the WinRT version of it.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            Caption = "",
            Message = "",
            LeftButtonContent = "ok"
        };

        messageBox.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MessageDialog class can be used for this purpose

See :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: I want it when the page opens not just to show it. What needs to change in my code?